# Redirecting Mobile Users of My WordPress Site to My Subdomain "http://mobile."

Tags: wordpress

I have got a WordPress site and I Want to redirect my mobile users to my m.domain sub domain Not exactly sure how to approach it.

Comment: You can easily create a javascript redirect based on the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wp_is_mobile()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function.

Put this in the beginning of your `functions.php` file

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    header ('Location: http://m.domain.com');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) to redirect on mobile

Code Example

```
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( 'http://m.example-domain.com' );
    exit;
}
```